# Problems in recovering the fields with php

Tags: hooks, 7

1. How do I retrieve a field without first being written its title? Now I'm doing so: `print render ($ content ['field_text']);`
2. I tried to recall the title of a node: `print render ($ content ['title']);`
   but this is not the way

Answer (score 1):

In node.tpl.php, the title is available as $title.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7

In the case of full-page view of nodes, the title may be printed via page.tpl.php, so you may also need to modify that template to get the desired behavior.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7